# Running angularjs without server

Tags: angularjs, jsp

I'm new to working in angular.js with jsp . I have 5 html pages in my application. In that, i have index.html .

In which i wrote ng-view directive and i have properly installed ngRoute and angular-route.js . 
I have tried something like this.

This is my index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
 <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="angular-route.js"></script>

 <script src="main.js"></script>
 <style>
   .table{
      width:1000px !important;
      height:400px !important;
      margin-left:25px;
      margin-top:20px !important;
    }
  .hover{
        cursor:pointer;
   }    
 </style>
   <div ng-view></div>
 </html>
```

This is my login.html

```
<form role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address:</label>
      <input type="email"ng-model="username"  class="form-control" id="email">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" ng-model="passwrd" class="form-control" id="pwd">
   </div>
   <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="login(username,passwrd)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my main.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);  

app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeprovider){
   $routeprovider.when('/',{
      templateUrl:'login.html',
      controller:loginController
   })
  .when('/demo',{
    templateUrl:'demo.html',
    controller:demoController
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'})
 }]);

 app.controller('indexController',function($scope,$http){
      alert('w3e3r'); 
 });

  app.controller("demoController",function($scope,$http){
     $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").
     success(function(data){    $scope.demoArr = data.records}).
     error(function(error){
     console.log(error);
   });
  });   

 app.controller("loginController",function($scope){

 });
```

There is no server. I'm running pages directly from my local hard disk drive. while trying to load pages directly bootstrap is not applied and ng-view also not working. Need some help to do this.

Help me

Thanks in advance...

Comment: In app.config -- controller values should be strings -- `controller: 'loginController'` etc.

Comment: Need to run it from server so the ajax works to get templates and data. Numerous easy ways to set up localhost server in very short time. Browsers don't like ajax in `file://` protocol for security reasons

Comment: If you can install node.js it would be great, as in your $routeprovider you are saying "if my URL is this '/' " then do load pages. since you are access it thru file system. this way it wont work

Comment: Why is this tagged with jsp?

Comment: Bcas, i want to do the same in jsp too... i want to use jsp instead of html as well